# how to calculate $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^{3}-2\sin(x)+\sin(2x)}{\arctan(x^{3})-\arctan^{3}(x)}$

Tags: limits

is there any way to solve this limit I tried many tricks but all of them leads me to an Indeterminate form.
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{x^{3}-2\sin(x)+\sin(2x)}{\arctan(x^{3})-\arctan^{3}(x)}$$

sorry, it was a typo I rectified.

Comment: Are you allowed to use L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: yes, you can use it

Comment: I was asking because of the tag "limits-without-lhopital".

Answer (score 2):

You can use the first few terms of the power series expansions of $\sin $ and $\arctan $ to find that for small $x$ the numerator is $2x + \cdots$ and the denominator is $x^5+\cdots$, so that the limit will be infinite.  A calculator will illustrate the point.

A more interesting limit is
$$
\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x^3-2 \sin x + \sin 2x}{\arctan x - \arctan^3 x}
$$
in which the same approach tells you the limit is $1/4$.

---

Seeing the question has been corrected, I can expand on the 'more interesting' limit.  Using power series expansions, the numerator becomes $x^5/4 + \cdots$ and the denominator is still $x^5 + \cdots$ where the dots indicate higher powers of $x$.  Thus the limit can be seen to be $1/4$

Comment: I guess that the problem is what you wrote at the end.